# How to include special part in regex to find English names using python re.findall?

Tags: python, regex

I have a python code like below to search all the English names:

```
a = "Bonds met Susann (&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth Branco, the mother of his first two children, in {{city-state|Montreal|Quebec}} in August 1987. They eloped in {{city-state|Las Vegas|Nevada}} Barry Bonds"

re.findall("(?:[A-Z][a-z'.]+\s*){1,4}",a)
```

I want it to return :

```
['Bonds', 'Susann (&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth Branco', 'Montreal', 'Quebec', 'August', 'They', 'Las Vegas','Nevada','Barry Bonds']
```

My code cannot get what I want, How to modify the regex to achieve my goal?

And I want to add that I used another regex, `(?:(([A-Z][a-z'.]+)|(\(&quot.*&quot;\)))\s*){1,4}`. I test it on [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com), it finds what I want on that test website, but in Python, it just doesn't return what I want, but returns me `Susan` and `(&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth` and `Branco`, three separately, but I want `Susan (&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth Branco` in my result

Comment: Matching all English names is not something that can be accomplished using regex.

Comment: I don't want a regex to match all english name, I just want a regex to work with this case.

Comment: Try dropping that last parameter, the RE.I. You don't want the match to be case insensitive. You're trying to match capital first letters.

Comment: @PeitiPeterLi: "In this case" what defines an english name versus a generic word?

Comment: @JoelCornett: Judging from the example, capitalization.

Comment: Yes, at most 4 consecutive Cap words concatenated by space or something that contains the "&quot;" inside

Comment: @JoelCornett I don't need to distinguish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the string with "&quto" looked as delimit as well:

```
re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]*(?:(?:\\S*&quot\\S*|\\s)+[A-Z][a-z]*){0,3}", "Bonds met Susann (&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth Branco, the mother of his first two children, in {{city-state|Montreal|Quebec}} in August 1987. They eloped in {{city-state|Las Vegas|Nevada}} Barry Bonds")
```

Output:

```
['Bonds', 'Susann (&quot;Sun&quot;) Margreth Branco', 'Montreal', 'Quebec', 'August', 'They', 'Las Vegas', 'Nevada', 'Barry Bonds']
```